RDS load below provisioned IOPS but still eating away byte balance?
We have a large AWS RDS running, but recently we have seen poor disk performance. We have narrowed it down to our EBSByteBalance going to 0, resulting in high latency for read & writes to the disk.
According to the docs of the underlying gp2 storage, we should have a baseline IOPS of 12k. (we have 4,000+ GB storage size)

If I check the metrics, it seems like we never hit that 12k IOPS limit. Still, our EBSByteBalance gets drained:

Am I misinterpreting the available IOPS (12k) that we have?

Looking at the graph, it appears that your read + write exceeds your limit for a short duration (they're graphed separately). You don't say whether the graphs represent average, min, max, or some other statistic, so there's not much more that can be said, but the extended period of 0 balance does seem strange. AWS Support might be your best option.

Quick clarifications: graph is stacked, so it should be making the sum. Metric is the maximum. Applied for a trial of AWS support - but it's slow to get it approved :(

What is the instance type you are using, even though you had enough IOPS some times when there is a heavy read and write activity and available RAM might drift too. Try increasing to higher instance type from the current.

The turned out to be the limited network capacity from the RDS to the disk. The graph of our network traffic shows that we do cross the provisioned amount there (2780 Mbps for our instance type).
The question remains how to fix this issue, since the instance type is already maxed out.


If that's your max EBS, then it indicates that you're using one of the "burstable" instance types. If it's the maximum spec, that's db.t4g.2xlarge, with 8 vCPU and 32 GB RAM. You could switch to a db.m7g.2xlarge, which has similar specs but "up to 10,000 Mbps" EBS bandwidth for a slight increase in price ($0.674/hour versus $0.517). Hardware specs are here, pricing is here.

In my experience, one of the best cures for high IOPS is more memory: let the database disk cache do its thing. It's worth at least trying one of the "memory optimized" instance types. Switching to a db.r6g.2xlarge gives you 8 vCPU and 64 GB RAM, for $0.859/hour (unreserved).

Other than that, you need to look at your usage patterns. Are you doing expensive selects? If yes, then a read replica might help, although it will increase your costs (but at the same time give you higher reliability, in case the primary's AZ goes down). If you only need that read replica for part of the day, consider switching to Aurora. If your load is particularly bursty then you could try an Aurora Serverless database, which will scale up according to load (although I'm not comfortable enough with that to recommend it without an extensive trial using real-world query volumes).

Thanks for the suggestions, didn't think of changing the instance family! db.m7g.2xlarge and db.r6g.2xlarge look interesting indeed.
